# What is wrong with this class?

Tags: powershell

I have a class `myClass` with the method `A()` but when I try to call `A` it always can't find it and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
class Main
{
    [int]$A
    [string]$B
    [bool]$C
}

class myClass : Main
{
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }

    [void] A([string]$Argument) {
        Write-Host $Argument
        $This.C = $True
    }
}
```

I defined the class like this and then did:

```
PS C:\> $Class = [myClass]::New()
PS C:\> $Class.A()
Method invocation failed because [myClass] does not contain a method named 'A'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $Class.A()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have both a property and a method named `A`. Try changing the name of one of them.

Comment: Changed to `AM` now getting error `Cannot find an overload for "AM" and the argument count: "0".
At line:1 char:1
+ $Class.AM()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest`

Comment: You have a member `A` already, from `Main`, which is not a method. What exactly did you expect to happen here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but `A` and `A()` are different

Comment: @newbieprogrammer Your new error stems from the fact that you provided no arguments when the method needs 1, `$Argument`

Comment: Overloads are just methods with the same name but different argument counts, so `[void] m1($Arg)` and `[void]m1()` are different

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is correct, since both properties and methods are members, you cannot have both a member and property have the same name though you would indeed call them differently, `A()` and `A`. Use `Get-Member` on your class variable to see this.

Comment: Put the argument and it works, thank you @NekoMusume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two members with the same name. Property `A` and method `A` are both he same name therefore causing the error.

---

Your class has two **members** with the same name, `[int]$A` and `[void]A([string]$Argument)`. Yes, one is a *property* (`[int]$A`) and the other a *method* (`[void]A([string]$Argument)`) and they are called differently, (`$var.A` and `$var.A()`) but they are both members that you can see from the `Get-Member` cmdlet, however, since they both have the same name, the one defined earlier will take priority over the other, which in this case is your property, `[int]$A`

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $Test = [myClass]::new()
PS C:\Users\Neko> $Test | Get-Member


   TypeName: myClass

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
A           Method     void A(string Argument)
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
B           Property   string B {get;set;}
C           Property   bool C {get;set;}
```

But if you change the name so that they are different, like

```
class Main
{
    [int]$A
    [string]$B
    [bool]$C
}

class myClass : Main
{
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }

    [void] AM([string]$Argument) {
        Write-Host $Argument
        $This.C = $True
    }
}
```

Now if I use `Get-Member`, I should be able to see the method `AM`:

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $Test = [myClass]::new()
PS C:\Users\Neko> $Test | Get-Member


   TypeName: myClass

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
AM          Method     void AM(string Argument)
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
A           Property   int A {get;set;}
B           Property   string B {get;set;}
C           Property   bool C {get;set;}
```

Which as you can see in the `Name` column doesn't have the `()` so `A` and `A()` wouldn't be different in the parser's eyes.

Now I can use `$test.AM("Argument")`

```
PS C:\Users\Neko> $Test.AM("Argument")
Argument
PS C:\Users\Neko> $Test

A B           C
- -           -
1 Property True
```

And as you can see, it outputted `Argument` and changed `C` to `True`